# Restart server from bash console

Tags: bash, pythonanywhere

Is there any way to restart the web server from within the `bash` console given in the browser for `PythonAnywhere`? I have searched google for a while and have not found anything relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a file for each of your web apps in `/var/www`. The naming of the file should make it obvious which file applies to which web app.

Type

```
touch /var/www/<filename>
```

(where <filename> is the name of the file that is for the web app you want to restart) and server will notice that the modified date of the file has changed and restart your app.

Comment: Is there any delay from the time the date is modified to the server seeing it and thus restarting?

Comment: There is a small delay - should be a few seconds for ordinary web apps. If your web app does something long and difficult at startup, that would slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted by harry, one of the people working at PythonAnywhere on the PA forum https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/89/#id_post_4289

> touching the file at /var/www/you-domain-wsgi.py will reload your web app workers, so that will pick up on any code changes you've made, but be warned that it doesn't do the other stuff which the button does, in particular, it won't pick up any new static files directory mappings you've made.

To perform a full reload, you can use [this script](https://github.com/ayys/pareload#) on github.

`git clone https://github.com/ayys/pareload.git`

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere has since added a [API](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/API) as well as a number of [helper scripts](https://github.com/pythonanywhere/helper_scripts) including a script to reload a webapp from the console:

```
pip3.5 install --user pythonanywhere
pa_reload_webapp.py <domain>
```

Be sure to [generate a API token](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/generaladmission/account/#api_token) before running a script.