# How to restart pythonanywhere console by code

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, pythonanywhere

I am runing telegram bot on pythonanywhere , sometimes i get errors and bot stopped working. i am looking for a way to restart my console as exception
for example :

```
try :
 bot.polling(none_stop=True)
except:
 restart_console()
```

Comment: this might be it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434327/restart-server-from-bash-console

Comment: Do you mean clear or restart?

Comment: @ whackamadoodle3000 i think restart . i mean close this session and run new (if its possible to say session)

Comment: @yklsga  iam not using web server , iam just running console

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- consoles do get restarted from time to time due to system maintenance etc.   If you have a paid account, you can use a trick with scheduled tasks to keep it running indefinitely -- [more information here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/LongRunningTasks/).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to restart console, just replace `bot.polling(none_stop=True)` with `bot.infinity_polling(True)` - even with error "timeout..." bot is working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are trying to run the script again.
try the subprocess module to run it again.
Beside, in order to prevent infinity loop, remember to check the return value of the call function.

`subprocess.call(['python','script.py'])`