# Ctrl+C Doesn't Let Me Quit the Server | Python Django

Tags: python, django, bash, server, pythonanywhere

I am using PythonAnywhere to create a Django application following Corey Schafer's Youtube series on Django. For some reason in the BASH console I cannot exit the server in order to restart it using CTRL-C. When I do CTRL-C-enter nothing happens, and to check that it hasn't stopped, I run "python3.6 manage.py runserver" and it says that the port is still in use, hence proving that it the CTRL-C has not worked. How else can I close the server?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434327/restart-server-from-bash-console

Comment: @hansTheFranz tried this but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it depends on the OS settings. for example, I stopped the server when pressing the keys **"shift+ctrl+c"**

Answer (score 0):

Running a Django site using `manage.py runserver` does nothing on PythonAnywhere apart from start up a server that isn't connected to the Internet.  If you want to restart your server, and you've set it up on the "Web" page, then click the green "Reload" button on that page.

(The "port in use" error that you're getting is probably because another user on the same physical machine is also running a `runserver` command unnecessarily.)